# RecyclerView notifyItemMoved not working

Tags: android

hi there guys I have an issue, when i call notifyItemMoved, the items move but at the end they stay the same as before, why is that happening?
Here´s the part of the code (notice that I want the second item in the adaper to move to the first position, that is position 0)

```
 InboxFragment.mRecyclerView.setAdapter(InboxFragment.inboxAdapter);
 InboxFragment.inboxAdapter.notifyItemMoved(1, 0);
```

Comment: Did you actually move the item in the adapter's data?

Comment: no, i just add thoose two lines, how can I do that? please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your adapter has an array of data in it (by the way your code implies that the adapter is static - it is advisable to make it a member variable).

So your code should look something like:

```
class InboxFragment extends Fragment {
    Data data[];
    InboxAdapter inboxAdapter;
    void moveItem(){
        Data tmp = data[0];
        data[0] = data[1];
        data[1] = tmp;
        inboxAdapter.notifyItemMoved(1, 0);
    }
}
```